# Field name from data values in Apache Solr

Tags: solr

I have  2 SQL tables for indexing in Solr:

**items** and **params**

In table items - 2 fields :

**id** and **name**

In table params - 3 fields :

**item_id**, **param_name** and **param_value**

so I have in config:

```
<document>
    <entity name="item" query="select * from items" >
        <field column="id" name="id" />
         <field column="name" name="name" />

        <entity name="params"  
                query="select param_name, param_value from items where item_id ='${item.id}'">
            <field name="param_value" column="param_value" />
        </entity>

    </entity>
</document>
```

and I have schema:

```
<field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="param_value" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

and result of object will be:

```
{  
    "id":"894",
   "name":"item_name1",
   "param_value":[  
      "param_value1",
      "param_value2",
      "param_value3",
      "param_value4"
   ]
}
```

but i want object to be:

```
{  
   "id":"894",
   "name":"item_name1",
   "param_name1":"param_value1",
   "param_name2":"param_value2",
   "param_name3":"param_value3",
   "param_name4":"param_value4"
}
```

How can I do this? name of field must be taken from one of result values. I can`t find any example to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND SOLUTION!!
 In data config add script transformer for data:

```
<dataConfig>
  <script><![CDATA[
              function FieldValueProcess(row)    {
              var row_id = ""+row.get('param_name');
              var row_data = ""+row.get('param_value');
               row.put(row_id, row_data);
               row.remove('param_name');
               row.remove('param_value');
               return row;
             }

 ]]></script>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
          driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/xxx" 
                                      user="xx" 
                                                    password="xxx"/>
<document>
<entity name="item" query="select * from items" >
     <entity name="params" transformer="script:FieldValueProcess"
            query="select param_name, param_value from items where item_id ='${item.id}'">
    </entity>

    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

in schema.xml add dynamicField:

```
<dynamicField name="*" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a dynamic filed in solr, and the config should support that. You can use [this](http://charlesnagy.info/it/solr-dynamic-field-with-data-importer) for usinig transformers in the config and then index it.

Comment: Thanks! Already found the same solution. And post it at the same time as you.